# Windows can't find the issuer of a client certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, x509, pki

Hello and sorry about my bad english. I have a problem about a PKI which I did on Ubuntu using OpenSSL: when I installed the root certificate on Windows (it's a simple hierarchy: ROOT -> Intermediate -> Client) and after that, open the client certificate I got a Windows' message which says something like this: "Windows don't have enough information to validate this certificate". Also, in the third tab of that dialog in the certificate status says: "Windows can't find the issuer of this certificate". To fix that, I installed the intermediate certificate too and that error message dissapears.

So, what I did wrong to get that problem? And how can I fix that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both the root and the intermediary certificates.  If you control the root certificate, why not skip the intermediary?

Comment: I don't skip it because I want to... eh? "centralize"? the certificate's control. Also, I have more than 1 intermediary certificate... and if I want to revoke some of them to expend it again... well... I think deploy them again aren't the best way to do it if I'm making a PKI. That's why :)

Comment: Since this is not a "real" root certificate provider, and the intermediaries cannot be verified through normal means... you need to install the root and all intermediaries.  There is no other way to get windows to be able to validate your certificate chain.  You could try combining the intermediaries with the client certificate in one key.

Comment: And how can I do that? Concatenation?

Comment: ... concatenation.  Typically you would start with root, followed by intermediaries, and finally the client cert.

Comment: @AldoAstupillo - concatenation of what?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work :(

Comment: What is this certificate being used for?  and what format?  PEM?

Comment: You cannot have 1 client certificate signed by 3 intermediaries for 3 different purposes...

Comment: It's used for client-server communications (at least, this one) signed by a Intermediary A. But I have another client certificates signed by another Intermediaries with another purposes.

Comment: And well, I'm going to deploy all the certificates on the PKI to the computer's group. Thanks for your help, dude! :)

Comment: In windows, you should be able to open the .pem directly, and it should show you the certificate chain and should give you indications at what point it fails.  Can you tell me which certificate is failing, and what point?

Comment: Client, when it tries to find the issuer (intermediary), doesn't matter if I installed the root.

Comment: And well, it works well on Ubuntu, so...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it :D ... I put Authority Information Access data in the client certificate, and upload the intermediary certificate to my website (pointed in AIA data) and... IT WORKS! :D ... Windows downloaded the intermediary into CryptoAPI cache and voilá! No more errors :3